# Enable macros via PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, macro

I created init code for a project's layers' forms using Python.
If I add features now, QGIS will complain that macros are disabled.
I would like to disable that warning and enable macros via Python.

As required by @PolyGeo I have to provide minimal code of an example init code, even if it has no relevance at all, so here it is:

```py
def irrelevant_function_that_does_nothing():
    pass
```

How can I enable macros for a running QGIS session using PyQGIS Python code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS uses the `qgis/enableMacros` settings entry to determine whether macros are enabled or not. I am not aware of any specific API method to change that setting, but you can write the settings entry yourself using the following code snippet:

`QgsSettings().setEnumValue("qgis/enableMacros", Qgis.PythonMacroMode.SessionOnly)`

The second argument is of type [`Qgis::PythonMacroMode`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a7893804c0b14f2c0126161421aa6090c), so you can also choose `Qgis.PythonMacroMode.Always` to keep macros enabled across sessions.